# I select and then deselect a row in listview it returned as selected

Tags: android, listview

I am facing problem in ListView with selecting and then deselecting Checkbox. I have a button in which i am bypassing all the selected items of a list. But i check and then uncheck, it returned as checked.I am using sparse boolean array.
Here is my code-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(addProductAdapter.mCheckedState.size()==0){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,SELECT_PRODUCTS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else{

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < addProductAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            if (addProductAdapter.mCheckedState.get(i) == true) {
                //ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
                // for(int j = 0;j<=productObject.size();j++){
                ProductEntity productEntity = (ProductEntity) productObject
                        .get(i);
                ProductsEntity pe = new ProductsEntity();
                pe.setProcdut_name(productEntity.getName());
                pe.setUnit_price(productEntity.getUnitPrice());
                pe.setTotal_price(productEntity.getUnitPrice());
                pe.setQuantity("1");
                list.add(pe);
               // arrayList.add(list);
            }
        }
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(RESULT, list);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();

    }
}
```

here is my adapter class`private Context context;

```
    private int resourceId;
    private List<Object> objArrayList;
    public SparseBooleanArray mCheckedState;


    public AddProductsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Object> objList ) {
        super(context, resource,objList);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = resource;
        mCheckedState = new SparseBooleanArray(objList.size());
        this.objArrayList = objList;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View productview = convertView;
        ProductHolder productHolder;
        if (productview == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            productview = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            productHolder = new ProductHolder();
            productHolder.productNameView = (TextView) productview.findViewById(R.id.nameProductView);
            productHolder.productIdView = (TextView) productview.findViewById(R.id.IdProductView);
            productHolder.productPriceView = (TextView) productview.findViewById(R.id.priceProductView);
            productHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) productview.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxView);
            productview.setTag(productHolder);
            productview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ProductHolder productHolder = (ProductHolder) v.getTag();
                    if (productHolder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                        productHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    else{
                        productHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    }

                }
            });

}
        else{
            productHolder = (ProductHolder) productview.getTag();

        }
        try {

            if(objArrayList!=null){
            ProductEntity productEntity= (ProductEntity) objArrayList.get(position);
            String productName = productEntity.getName();

            String productId = productEntity.getProductId();
            String productPriceStandrd = productEntity.getStandard();

            productHolder.productNameView.setText(productName);
            productHolder.productIdView.setText(productId);
            productHolder.productPriceView.setText(productPriceStandrd);
            //productHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);
            productHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);
            productHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mCheckedState.get(position, false));
            productHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            }
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return productview;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckedState.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckedState.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objArrayList != null ? objArrayList.size() : 0;
    }

    private class ProductHolder {
        TextView productNameView;
        TextView productIdView;
        TextView productPriceView;
        CheckBox checkBox;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckedState.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
`
```

Comment: few remarks:
1) why you not using ProductEntity list instead of object list?
2) also why you need to use SparseBooleanArray, you could just add a boolean if the item is selected or not

Comment: 1-In my project scenario i have to use object list.2-For the memory management i used sparse boolean array.